# Programming a shortcut key to clear the results window in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to setup a shortcut key to clear any results from the results window in the base SAS IDE.

I know F9 brings up the shortcut window to assign keys.  From the ?command box? I can type in `dm results` to activate the results window, and then `clear` to clear it.  But when I try and combine these as my keyboard shortcut like so:

```
dm results; clear;
```

... nothing happens.  What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was writing a longer answer, but seems everything I wanted to say is gathered here:

http://support.sas.com/kb/4/159.html

For your specific question to clear the results by key shortcut: `odsresults; clear;`

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. You need to write:

```
DM ODSRESULTS "CLEAR;";
```

FYI:

```
DM LOG "CLEAR;";
```

Will clear your log as well.